# Symfony 4 - Validate a form sent from Vue

Tags: php, symfony, validation, vue.js

How can I validate (server side) a form created and submitted from Vue?

I have a simple contact form, and I want to validate it both client and server side. For the client mode I'm using [vee-validate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) (and it works), for the server side mode **I want to use the Symfony's form validation**.

So in this **"special"** case, the form is not rendered using the methods from Symfony, the form in this case is used only for validation. I have already created the form (it isn't linked to an Entity object), but when I send a http `post` request from my Vue's component, **the validation on server side doesn't work**. Seems that doesn't "read" the constraints created in the `FormType`class.

My **function**:

```
public function sendContactUsEmailAction(Request $request, Mailer $mailer, TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    try {
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactUsType::class);

        $form->submit($request->request->all());

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            $emailParams = new ContactUsParams();
            $emailParams->setName($data['name']);
            $emailParams->setEmail($data['email']);
            $emailParams->setSubject($data['subject']);
            $emailParams->setMessage($data['message']);

            $email = new ContactUsMail($mailer, $emailParams);
            $email->send();

            return new JsonResponse($translator->trans('send_contact_us_email_response'));
        }

        return new JsonResponse($this->getFirstFormError($form), 400);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return new JsonResponse($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```

**Edited**

This is the dump of my request data:

```
array:4 [
  "name" => "Example"
  "email" => "foo@example.com"
  "subject" => "Test subject"
  "message" => "Test message"
]
```

[image]

This is my FormType class. To test it I added for the name property the constraint "Email", but from the request I didn't send a valid email.

```
    class ContactUsType extends AbstractType
    {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Email(),
                ),
            ))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Email(),
                ),
            ))
            ->add('subject', TextType::class, array(
                'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
            ))
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array(
                'constraints' => new NotBlank(),
            ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'validation_groups' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "the validation on server side doesn't work" mean? Do you get validation errors? Is the data empty? How does the request you send look like?

Comment: @dbrumann and don't receive any validation erorrs, despite I add other constraints in my FormType class to see if they are applied. The request data are correct, I'm going to add them above

Comment: @dbrumann I also added the ContactUsType class. How you can see, I added the constraint "Email" for the name property. But from the request I didn't send a valid email address

Comment: What does the Response look like? If you run this request against the dev-environment the Response should have a header called `X-Debug-Token-Link` that leads you to the profiler output. There you should be able to inspect among other things additional info for form data.

Comment: @dbrumann cool. But I don't understand where is the error, this is the screen: https://screenshots.firefox.com/jX3eEOllUKrI4hzX/localhost . The field should be blank, but I sent a field with some content, why the value is correct?

Comment: It looks like it is using different constraints than in your ContactUsType-class shown above. Could it be you forgot to save it or have a duplicate version somehow? Maybe it is using a cached version and you should clear `var/cache` to make sure it is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was caused by the option "validation_groups" setted to false. I removed it and now works!